# dotnet core webapp doesn't have gpio access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, raspbian, gpio

I'm trying to get a aspnet core webapplication to run on my raspberry pi. The application uses Bifrost to interact with the GPIO's of the raspberry but everytime I do a `sudo dotnet run` it fails with the error

```
Using launch settings from /home/pi/Desktop/keypad-alarm/keypad-alarm-server/Properties/launchSettings.json...     
Write value High to pin at /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Operation not permitted    
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at 
System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)    at 
System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()    at 
System.IO.FileStream.FlushInternalBuffer()    at 
System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)    at 
System.IO.FileStream.Flush()    at 
System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)    at 
System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)  at 
System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()   
 at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)    at 
Bifrost.Devices.Gpio.GpioPin.Write(GpioPinValue pinValue)    at 
keypad_alarm_server.TweetController.Tweet(Int32 milliseconds) in 
/home/pi/Desktop/keypad-alarm/keypad-alarm-server/TweetController.cs:line 25    at 
keypad_alarm_server.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/pi/Desktop/keypad-alarm/keypad-alarm-server/Program.cs:line 15
```

I should mention that I immediately turn GPIO 17 on high to sound a beep before I even start the webserver in Program.cs.

How can I make sure dotnet has enough permissions to access the gpio's?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as always, after you've spend time posting the question, you find the answer somewhere...

The unauthorizedexception is terribly misleading as what was missing was the following statement in c#: `pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);`

```
public class TweetController
{
    private static IGpioController _gpio = null;
    private const int PIN = 17;

    public TweetController()
    {
        _gpio = GpioController.Instance;
    }

    public void Tweet(int milliseconds){
        var pin = _gpio.OpenPin(PIN);
        pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output); // open the gpio pin before writing or unauthorizedexception occurs
        pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
        pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    }
}
```